# Determine if object is of type Foo without importing type Foo

Tags: python, python-2.6, typechecking

Let's say I have a class defined in a file:

```
import stuff
import more stuff
import stuff that takes a long time to import
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2 etc.):
        self.arg1 = arg1 
        self.arg2 = arg2
        # Lots of other stuff
    # Lots of methods
```

And in another file I have this code:

```
from big_file import Foo
def do_stuff(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, Foo):
        do_stuff
    else:
        do_other_stuff
```

Let's say the file Foo takes a long time to import for reasons out of my control. How can I refactor this code to not import Foo but still reliably check the type? I don't think duck typing is appropriate for my particular case.

Should I e.g. check the string representations of the bases of the `obj`? Or is there another, more canonical way?

Comment: `obj.__class__.__name__ == 'Foo'`, but I wouldn't ever do this. Do you actually need to check the type, rather than using duck typing?

Comment: You could first look in `sys.modules` to see if `big_file` has been imported.  If it hasn't, then your object isn't a `Foo`.  If it has, you can import it on the spot very cheaply and do your `isinstance` check there.

Comment: If you have an instance of `Foo` , is there any situation in which the module where `Foo` is defined *won't* be in `sys.modules`? (other than purposely modifying `sys.modules`)

Comment: @mgilson I think you're on to something, are you going to write up a full answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Typically, this would be a non-issue. If you have an instance of `big_file.Foo`, then its parent module has already been imported earlier on even if not explicitly referenced from your other file. Python modules are only loaded once on the first import (provided you're not doing any explicit reloading or messing with `sys.modules`). Since it's already been imported, doing an `import big_file` in your other file should run instantaneously.

However, if your other file will only encounter a `big_file.Foo` under certain circumstances and `big_file` is only imported elsewhere when it's actually need, then you could inspect the object's class as such (this does not support subclasses):

```
def do_stuff(obj):
    if (obj.__class__.__module__, obj.__class__.__name__) == ('big_file', 'Foo'):
        do_stuff
    else:
        do_other_stuff
```

Since you've indicated that `big_file.Foo` could be imported at any point in the application and you want to support subclasses, you could check to see if its module has been imported and conditionally check the type.

```
import sys

def is_Foo(obj):
    if 'big_file' in sys.modules:
        return isinstance(obj, sys.modules['big_file'].Foo)
    else:
        return False

def do_stuff(obj):
    if is_Foo(obj):
        do_stuff
    else:
        do_other_stuff
```

Comment: What about the case when the object with type `Foo` had been restored by a serializer like `dill` or `pickle`? The `big_file` may not be imported then

Comment: @OlegRybalchenko I have minimal experience using `pickle`, but I thought it had to lookup the actual classes and import them, and then use `__getstate__` or `__setstate__`.

Comment: But if obj isn't `Foo`, then `Foo` wouldn't be imported and I don't want to spend time importing it. But like someone else suggested, I can check sys.modules to see if it has been imported

Comment: @C_Z_, looks like a good way if it's enough in your case. As an alternative, if you still need to lookup objects defined at the top-level of the module, take a look at `pyclbr` from the standard library

Comment: Thanks for your update. The update does not directly replace the code I had written, however, because `isinstance()` also checks for base types, which your code does not. So if I have object Bar, which is a subclass of Foo, it wouldn't get properly caught

Comment: @C_Z_ Unfortunately, there's no way to check for subclasses of `Foo` without either importing `Foo`, or having a list of all of its subclasses to check.

Comment: Right, I understand in some cases importing Foo is necessary. Going to have to downvote for now because this doesn't replicate the behavior in the question though

Comment: Can't you check the MRO of an object? e.g. `inspect.getmro(type(obj))` you could check all the class names in the MRO... though I don't think any of this is particularly recommended.

Comment: Now this is getting interesting, although I think you would have to move the sys.modules check to inside the function. After all, if later on we DO import Foo we want to make sure the check works,

Comment: This does seem like a good solution. Not sure which is more robust, this or checking the string representation

Answer (score 4):

If `big_file` really does take a long time to import for whatever non-standard reason, you can indeed make use of the `str` representation. Here is a rather robust implementation:

```
from big_file import Foo

def isFoo(obj):
    try:
        return obj.__module__ == 'big_file' and type(obj).__name__ == 'Foo'
    except:
        return False

print(isFoo(Foo(...)))
print(isFoo(42))
```

The `isFoo` function test whether the passed `obj` is an instance of some class named `Foo` defined in a module named `big_file`. This can in principle fail if you have multiple modules with this same name e.g. in different packages, but of course this will most likely not be a problem for you.

#### Edit, taking care of subclasses of Foo

As pointed out by sytech, the above solution fails on subclasses. That is, `isFoo(obj)` returns `False` if `obj` is an instance of a subclass of `Foo`, whereas `isinstance(obj, Foo)` returns `True`. The below code is a generalized version of the above, fixing this issue:

```
import inspect

def isFoo(obj):
    for cls in inspect.getmro(type(obj)):
        try:
            if cls.__module__ == 'big_file' and cls.__name__ == 'Foo':
                return True
        except:
            pass
    return False
```

This utilizes the same test as before, but now on not just the `class` of `obj` but also all of its superclasses.

#### Edit, making the idea fail proof

The only caveat to the above is the fact that we only test for the module *name* and not the absolute path. As already stated, this is only a problem if your project contains multiple modules with the same name, containing identically named classes. We *can* however test for the path, though of course this require you to specify the absolute path to the module in your code:

```
import inspect

def my_isinstance(obj, classinfo):
    if isinstance(classinfo[0], str):
        classinfo = (classinfo, )
    for module_path, cls_name in classinfo:
        for cls in inspect.getmro(type(obj)):
            try:
                if inspect.getmodule(cls).__file__ == module_path and cls.__name__ == cls_name:
                    return True
            except:
                pass
    return False

print(my_isinstance(Foo(1, 2), ('/path/to/big_file.py', 'Foo')))
print(my_isinstance(42, ('/path/to/big_file.py', 'Foo')))
```

To make the function fully analogous to the builtin `isinstance`, it now also supports multiple classes as input (e.g. `tuple`s of the form `(('/path/to/module1.py', 'Foo'), ('/path/to/module2.py', 'Bar'))`, for checking if `obj` is an instance of either `Foo` or `Bar`).

Though this version is bullet proof, I personally like the previous `isFoo` better, as specifying the absolute path to the module is a bit ugly.

Comment: One issue with this can be if you have an object that is an instance of a subclass of `Foo`. `isinstance` works for subclasses. This implementation does not, so the behavior is not quite the same.

Comment: @cpburnz Thanks, I've updated the answer. Is `isinstance(obj, Foo)` guaranteed to return `True` just because `type(obj)` is in the call tree (method resolution order) of `Foo`? Can you provide a reference for this? Note that in Python, classes which are not direct ancestors of `type(obj)` can appear in the call tree.

Comment: @cpburnz Great. I didn't like the `tuple` concatenation anyway.

Comment: @jmd_dk Yes, `isinstance()` is guaranteed to return `True` if the class is anywhere in the call tree. See [isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance).